# Installing and using CodeIgniter on macOS?

Tags: macos, safari, high-sierra, php

I followed [this](https://www.codexworld.com/codeigniter-rest-api-web-services/) tutorial online and I'm currently running macOS High Sierra.

I tried a simple rest API using PHP and now I'm trying to implement it using **CodeIgniter3.x** framework. The one I created can successfully POST and GET using [Postman app](https://www.getpostman.com), but now that I tried following the tutorial, I encounter the following error:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>404 Not Found</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Not Found</h1>
        <p>The requested URL /~paul/CodeIgniter/api/example/user/ was not found on this server.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

The URL that I used last time when I created my own API is:

```
http://localhost/~paul/v1/login.php
```

I think there's some issue with installation/configuration of CodeIgniter on my Mac. How do I debug it and resolve the issue?

The following is a screenshot from the `Sites` directory.

[image]

Comment: Can you browse here and see CodeIgniter? http://localhost/~paul/CodeIgniter/ ? Might be /codeigniter/

Comment: @Alex localhost/~paul/CodeIgniter/ or localhost/~paul/codeigniter they are appearing the same.